# Display for outside (sun)

Tags: microcontroller, led, display, 7segmentdisplay

I am currently working on a little project where I would like to have a display which would have to support this format:

> 00 00:00:00

This would have to be used outside on a motorcycle (motocross). Basically it would only be used in sunny weather or only when it's raining very little.
The display would have to be connected to a microcontroller with very little ports (Adafruit Trinket or some sort).
I was thinking about [7- and 8-segmented LED's](http://www.uctronics.com/static/images/20130425/common-anode-red-segment-led-inch-056-04a18694-800x800.jpg) which would result in a format:

> 00 00.00.00

Which would be totally fine. I know there are also [prebuilt arrays](http://www.robot-italy.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/image/d43192dcd82ea942982b4b1d2a6e2479/0/9/09481-01_2.jpg) of these segmented LED's.

Now my question: Would this be the best way to have a clear visible display in the sun light which can withstand some bounces?
If so, how can I make sure that all ports needed (58 = 7+7+7+8+7+8+7+7), fit my few ports?
I have heard about some possibility to need lesser ports and put some component in between, but I have no clue what it is and how it works.

A little note: it should be as low as possible in price (but still be solid and strong);

Comment: Bright daylight visibility can be a challenge. There are some excellent daylight viewable LCD displays available. || A standard smartphone screen with a degree of shielding from direct light can work remarkably well in bright light - and may be the easiest way to experiment with variable character sizes and styles.

Comment: LCD displays wich are "transflective" are usually best for this kind of application.

Comment: Seems like everybody thinks I should go for an LCD instead of the segmented led's. Interesting and that would also eliminate the problem with 58 ports needed.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to see it in sunlight you should use a 7 segment LCD display like this:

[image]

Image from [alibaba.com](http://japanese.alibaba.com/product-gs/7-segment-lcd-panel-lcd-display-screen-for-pressure-instrument-622025345.html)

To see it in the dark, choose one with backlight.

To save pins, you could use a [BCD to 7 segment](http://www.doctronics.co.uk/4511.htm) decoder like [CD4511](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf). For each digit you need 4 instead of 7 pins. This makes it also easier to interface with the microcontroller (write directly the value to be displayed to a 4 bit port for each digit).

Comment: You could also look into Shift Registers (e.g. 74HC595) to save pins. With 4 pins you can control an (practically) infinite number of outputs if you cascade them. In you case you could just use 8 Shift Registers.
This is the sollution with the least amount of components and soldering work.