# LED matrix display - outdoor

Tags: led-matrix

In my application the user needs to read a few simple shapes and characters under the bright sunlight. In terms of visibility, what would be the ideal solution? I am basically looking for experience of previous implementors or some research on the subject. Currently considering simple LED matrix (8x8) and blue color.

Comment: Look here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/111389/40609

Comment: "Transflective" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transflective_liquid-crystal_display

Answer (score 2):

You can use ultra bright or super bright leds to make displays, put shade on the displays and these are fairly visible during daytime. Just think of traffic LED lights a bunch is much more brighter. Therefore use  multiple leds to make a dot , be carefull with the rains.

You should also provide more info on your project, is it for outdoor fixed use, or movable?

Answer (score 2):

Use some good old Histogram Equalization to reduce glare effects, reduce shadow effects, and bring out colours better. Then process the image for "Chromaticity" - the equation is very simple and is seen on this [Wiki page with an explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity).

If you then examine the blue colour values only of the RGB image, you will see it very well indeed.

I have done this kind of colour space processing before in robotics, and even tutored a unit relating to this (coloured targets for robot arm movement). I did not actually do Histo-equalization though, but in outdoor environments give it a shot.

I suggest if you have access to MATLAB that you check out my professor's MATLAB Toolbox, by Peter Corke (very well known guy in robotic vision and control. [check out his textbook for direct use with this toolbox and examples](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642201431) )

His toolbox allows really quick image processing and will at least give you some decent examples for your own work. [Get the toolbox here](http://www.petercorke.com/Machine_Vision_Toolbox.html)